# Closure in JavaScript vs PHP

Tags: javascript, php, closures

I am trying to implement a very simple closure related task in PHP which is not going well. I have this solution in JavaScript. How do i implement this in PHP?

```
const data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20]

const getChunksOfTwo = () => {
  let pos = 0
  
  return () => {
     const start = pos
     const finish = start + 2
     const chunk = data.slice(start, finish)
     pos++
     return chunk
  }
}

// To initiate the closure
const closureFun = getChunksOfTwo()

// Call the closureFun
closureFun() // Gives [1, 2]
closureFun() // Gives [2, 3]
closureFun() // Gives [3, 4]
```

But in PHP the same apparently does not work. I am trying this:

```
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

function getChunksOfTwo($data) {
   $pos = 0;

   return function() {
     $start = $pos;
     $finish = $start + 2;
     $chunk = array_slice($data, $start, $finish);
     $pos++;
     return $chunk;
   };
};

// To initiate the closure
$closureFun = getChunksOfTwo($data);

// Call the closureFun
$closureFun(); // Does not give [1, 2]
$closureFun(); // Does not give [2, 3]
```

Comment: hi @ikhvjs, thanks. yes i forgot to put that there but still not working. :(

Comment: You can give the inner function access to your outer variables via [use](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php). Like `return function() use ($pos, $data) {}`

Comment: @Reyno, why don't you answer it?

Comment: @ikhvjs Because the output will still be incorrect.

Comment: @Reyno, I see. I leave my answer then. :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try this

```php
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

function getChunksOfTwo($data) {
   $pos = 0;
   
   return function() use(&$pos, $data) {
     $start = $pos;
     $finish = 2;
     $chunk = array_slice($data, $start, $finish);
     $pos+=2;
     return $chunk;
   };
};

// To initiate the closure
$closureFun = getChunksOfTwo($data);

// Call the closureFun
print_r($closureFun()); // gives [1, 2]
print_r($closureFun()); // gives [2, 3]
```

Or

```php
$data = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];

function getChunksOfTwo($data) {
   $chunks = array_chunk($data, 2);
   $pos = 0;
   
   return function() use(&$pos, $data, $chunks) {
     return $chunks[$pos++];
   };
};

// To initiate the closure
$closureFun = getChunksOfTwo($data);

// Call the closureFun
print_r($closureFun()); // gives [1, 2]
print_r($closureFun()); // gives [2, 3]
```

`&` with var means passing by reference [source](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)

It has to be passed by reference to mutate that variable otherwise it copies the original and every new call will have the same value.

Outupt

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
```

Comment: the output is wrong.

Comment: Thanks @n1md7, its great but the every other function call adding extra item in the arrray

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 2
    [1] => 3
    [2] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
    [2] => 5
    [3] => 6
)
```

Comment: @tonimora This is because in JS the `slice` method requires an end index while PHP requires a length. So just change (in PHP) your code to `$finish = 2` and it should work

Comment: Great! Thanks. I am very new to the PHP but that works. Cheers!

Comment: You can use array chunks as suggested by @SimoneRossaini. I modified the code a bit.

Comment: @n1md7, the problem is not using the wrong function but misunderstanding of the function. It is better to let OP understand why he is wrong than what is right.

Answer (score 1):

There are two issues in your `php` codes.

First is a closure in `PHP` encapsulates its scope, meaning that it has no access to the scope in which it is defined or executed. It is, however, possible to inherit variables from the parent scope (where the closure is defined) into the closure with the `use` keyword. This inherits the variables `by-value`, a copy is made available inside the closure using its original name.

As you want to keep the value of `$pos` for each function call, you need to pass it by reference with `&$pos`.

Second, the implementation of `array_slice` in `php` is different from `slice` in `js`. So, you need to change your input in the php.

```
<?php
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20];

function getChunksOfTwo($data) {
    $pos = 0;

    return function () use ($data, &$pos) {
        $chunk = array_slice($data, $pos, 2);
        $pos++;
        return $chunk;
    };
};

// To initiate the closure
$closureFun = getChunksOfTwo($data);

// Call the closureFun
print_r($closureFun());
print_r($closureFun());
print_r($closureFun());
```

Comment: Hi @ikhvjs, thanks a lot. Great answer and explanation! :)

Comment: @tonimora, you are welcome. if you think this is helpful, please mark it as answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I propose an alternative why not use `array_chunk`?

```
$data = [1,2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20];
$chunk = array_chunk($data, 2);
$pos = 0;
print_r($chunk[$pos]);
$pos++;
print_r($chunk[$pos]);
$pos++;
print_r($chunk[$pos]);
```

Output:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 1
    [1] => 2
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 4
)
Array
(
    [0] => 5
    [1] => 6
)
```

Reference:

- [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php)

Comment: Hi @Simone, thanks a lot but I need to call a function on inside the inner function based on that closure value being increased so the solution below worked for me. But great to know about array_chunk. Thank a lot!

Comment: You are welcome :), if you want you can +1 just for reference.